# Cannot access Hive internal tables-AccessControlException

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapr

My user id and my team cannot access any of the internal tables in hive db.   when we fire up the queries in HUE and 'CLI' as well, we are getting

> 'AccessControlException', please find the log below,

```
    INFO  : set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number> INFO  : Cleaning up the staging area maprfs:/var/mapr/cluster/yarn/rm/staging/keswara/.staging/job_1494760161412_0139 

ERROR : Job Submission failed with exception org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException
  (User keswara(user id 1802830393)  does not have access to 
   maprfs:///user/hive/warehouse/bistore_sit.db/wt_consumer/d_partition_number=0/000114_0)'
     org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: User keswara(user id 1802830393)  does not have access to maprfs:///user/hive/warehouse/bistore_sit.db/wt_consumer/d_partition_number=0/000114_0   
     at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.getMapRFileStatus(MapRFileSystem.java:1320)   
     at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.getFileStatus(MapRFileSystem.java:942)    
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileBlockLocations(FileSystem.java:741)  
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1762)   
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1747)      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:307)      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:265)      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop23Shims$1.listStatus(Hadoop23Shims.java:148)      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileInputFormat.getSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:218)      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat.getSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:75)      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getSplits(HadoopShimsSecure.java:310)      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getCombineSplits(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:472)      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getSplits(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:573)      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeOldSplits(JobSubmitter.java:331)      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:323)      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:199)      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)   
   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)   
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   
   at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:421)    
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1595)      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)   
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)    
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)  
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   
   at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:421)   
   at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1595)     
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:431)      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:137)      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)     
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:88)      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:75)
```

any of the user can't access the internal tables right now,am part of the mapr group and sudo user as well!

and the table and partitions ownership belongs to the mapr group and the permissions are look good though!

```
[mapr@SAN2LPMR03 mapr]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/bistore.db/wt_consumer
Found 1 items
drwxrwxrwt - mapr mapr 1 2017-03-24 11:51 /user/hive/warehouse/bistore.db/wt_consumer/d_partition_number=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__
```

Please help me to sort this out! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Looks like in the directory the users don't have permissions to read the files in that directory`maprfs:///user/hive/warehouse/bistore_sit.db/wt_consumer/d_partition_number=0/000114_0/ ` . Please check it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Viru reddy...i have changed the file permission with 777 ! now we can access those tables. yep..thats true...we are using the parquet format for those tables!? so what if we use parquet format for those tables???? can you please enlighten me on this !!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this knowledge Viru reddy . I really appreciate your help in this.

Comment: could you please accept and upvote my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tables are in `parquet` format then the files for that table will have write access only for the user who has created the table.

For this you can change the user permissions for that files using statement like below

```
hdfs dfs -chomd 777 /user/hive/warehouse/bistore_sit.db/wt_con‌​sumer/d_partitio‌​n_nu‌​mber=0/000114_‌​0/*
```

This statement will grant all users all the permissions to that particular files.

I have noticed the following while testing for some tables in both `CSV` and `parquet` formats.

When you create hive table in CSV format the table will have 777 permission for all users who have access to the group you are part of.

But when the hive table is created in parquet format only the user who has created the table will have write access. I think it has to do something with parquet format

Answer (score 0):

[root@psnode44 hive-2.1]# hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/

Found 1 items
drwxrw-rw-   - mapr mapr          2 2017-06-28 12:49 /user/hive/warehouse/test

0: jdbc:hive2://10.20.30.44:10000/> select *from test;

Error: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: User basa(user id 5005)  does not have access to maprfs:/user/hive/warehouse/test (state=,code=0)

[root@psnode44 hive-2.1]# hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/

Found 1 items
drwxrwxrwx   - mapr mapr          2 2017-06-28 12:49 /user/hive/warehouse/test

Even thought, I changed the  chmod on warehouse,still its getting same error.

[root@psnode44 hive-2.1]# hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/hive/warehouse/

[root@psnode44 hive-2.1]# hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/

Found 1 items
drwxrwxrwx   - mapr mapr          2 2017-06-28 12:49 /user/hive/warehouse/test

0: jdbc:hive2://10.20.30.44:10000/> select *from test;

Error: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: User basa(user id 5005)  does not have access to maprfs:/user/hive/warehouse/test (state=,code=0)